# How to archive an item instead of delete in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to mvc 5 c#, I want to archive items on the database instead of actually deleting it. The delete method I have on the controller:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Employee employee = emp.GetById(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

        // POST: /Employee/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            Employee employee = emp.GetById(id);
            emp.Delete(employee);
            //db.Employees.Remove(employee);
            //db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Thank You.

Comment: Deleting or archiving your employee has nothing to do with MVC. It is the handling of the back-end system. I would say, rename `emp.Delete(employee);` to `emp.Archive(employee);`

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please edit your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you or suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a new boolean column named `Deleted` in the table. Just make sure you check that value when you read again.

Answer (score 1):

I guess all you need is Soft delete for this refer below link:-

http://emerbrito.wordpress.com/2013/10/20/soft-delete-with-entity-framework/

As documented in the blow above :-

> When a user delete the record, instead of completely remove it from
>   the database we will flag the record is deleted and use this flag to
>   keep it out of all selects.

and follow the steps given in the link.